# Can the Marksman edge be used while duel wielding pistols?

Tags: savage-worlds, deadlands-reloaded

The marksman edge says

> The hero excels at taking controlled, measured shots. If he
>   does not move in a turn, he may fire as if he took the Aim
>   maneuver. Marksman may never be used with a Rate of Fire
>   greater than 1.
>   Marksman works with both Shooting and Throwing. <

If you have a pistol with ROF 1 in each hand can each shot benefit from the edge, or is that considered ROF 2?

Our group can't agree.  IMO based on this edge, it doesn't.. you need this edge for each gun to benefit.

> Pistolero
>   Requirements: Veteran, Marksman, Two-
>   Fisted, Shooting d10+
>   The gunslinger with this Edge can fire two
>   weapons with accuracy or speed. He can use
>   Marksman against two separate targets or he can
>   fire double-action pistols as if they had RoF 2. All
>   Automatic Fire rules are applied (–2 to Shooting
>   and uses two bullets per attack).<

Answer (score 9):

Marksman can be used with two pistols as long as you are shooting at the same target. See [here](http://archive.pegforum.com/viewtopic.php?f=56&t=40000&p=382790&hilit=marksman%20two%20pistols#p382790) for official confirmation of this.

> As long as both are fired at the same target. A character can't Aim (the bonus Marksman provides) at more than one target.
>
> *Clint Black - Forum Admin & Rules Answer Guy, Savage Worlds Brand Manager*

The Pistolero Edge extends this by allowing you to use Marksman against two different targets, or one target with ROF 2 as noted in its description.